# Group Theory: ord(ab) = ord(ba) - Proof

Tags: group-theory

If for some group with a binary operation, (G, *), we have ord $a$ := $a^n = 1$ for some positive integer $n$, would it be correct to argue that:

Case 1 (finite order): ord $ab$ = ord $ba$:

$(ab)^n = a^n b^n = 1 \iff b^n a^n b^n = b^n \iff b^n a^n (b^n (b^{-1})^n)=b^n (b^{-1})^n \iff $ $b^n a^n = (ba)^n= 1$

Case 2 (infinite order): ord $ab$ = ord $ba$:

ord $ab \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, and therefore ord $ab$ = ord $ba$

Do you think my proof is reliable?

Comment: If the group is not abelian the formula $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ does not necessarily hold. I'm afraid that ruins your calculation at its first step. Another thing worth emphasizing is that in the definition of order it is crucial that $n$ should be the **smallest** positive integer with the property $a^n=1$. Last but not least. Hint: try conjugation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$ is not true in groups.

For a finite order, I advise you to write

$$(ab)^n = abababab\dots ab = a(bababa\dots ba)a^{-1}$$

Comment: Would it be correct to argue, for the case where ord $a$ is infinite, that since $(ab)^n \to \infty$ and $(ba)^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, then ord $ab$ = ord $ba$?

Comment: @sequence The definition of "$x$ has infinite order" is "$x$ has infinite order if $x^n \neq e$ for all integers $n$." Therefore, you need to prove that $(ba)^n\neq e$.

Comment: Then, if I'm correct, the same approach as above is also good for infinite order.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a group. The element order of $g\in G$ is defined as the group order of the cyclic subgroup

$\langle g\rangle=\{g^n|n\in\mathbb Z\}$.

We have $b\langle ab\rangle=\{b(ab)^n|n\in\mathbb Z\}=\{(ba)^nb|n\in\mathbb Z\}=\langle ba\rangle b$.

Remember that for a subgroup $H\subseteq G$, all cosets $gH$ and $Hg$ have the same order as $H$.

We conclude $\operatorname{ord}(ab)=|\langle ab\rangle|=|b\langle ab\rangle|=|\langle ba\rangle b|=|\langle ba\rangle|=ord(ba)$.

(Note that with this proof, we need not distinguish between the finite and the infinite case.)

---

Alternatively, if you don't like using cosets, there's another easy proof for both cases at once:

This proof is more suitable if your lecture uses the definition $\operatorname{ord}(g)=\min\{n\in\mathbb N|g^n=1\}$.

$ab$ and $ba$ are conjugates, since $a^{-1}(ab)a=ba$.

Consequently, we have $(ba)^n=(a^{-1}(ab)a)^n=a^{-1}(ab)^na\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb Z$.

We conclude $(ba)^n=1\ \Leftrightarrow\ a^{-1}(ab)^na=1\ \Leftrightarrow\ a(a^{-1}(ab)^na)a^{-1}=aa^{-1}\ \Leftrightarrow\ (ab)^n=1$.

Therefore $\operatorname{ord}(ab)$ and $\operatorname{ord}(ba)$ must coincide.